# VSCode - Disable ALL Auto Formatting on Save

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm editing someone else's code and I only want to change 1 line of a 9000 line file. But every time I save, VS Code formats the entire file and removes any trailing white space. This is a no-no because when I push this up, the reviewer will have no idea which line to look at.

I've tried disabling prettier, adding all files to `.prettierignore`, going into VS Code settings and disabling any suggestions of a formatter or white space trimming, turning off `formatOnSave`.

Here is my `.vscode/settings.json`

```
{
  "prettier.disableLanguages": [
    "js",
    "json",
    "javascript"
  ],
  "javascript.format.enable": false,
  "typescript.format.enable": false,
  "json.format.enable": false,
  "html.format.enable": false,
  "emmet.showAbbreviationSuggestions": false,
  "css.validate": false,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": null,
  "editor.formatOnSave": false,
  "[javascript]": {
      "editor.formatOnSave": false,
      "editor.defaultFormatter": null
  },
  "editor.trimAutoWhitespace": false,
  "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false,
  "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": false,
  "files.trimFinalNewlines": false,
"eslint.format.enable": false,
"files.autoSave": "off",
}
```

The only thing that seems to work is if I do `CTRL + SHIFT + P`, then `SAVE WITHOUT FORMATTING`. But what setting can I have so I can just do that with normal saving?

Comment: I'm having this same issue in a slightly different context (can't get Prettier to ignore a local markdown file, even after adding `*.md` to a `.prettierignore` and a `.eslintignore` file in the local directory. `Save Without Formatting` is the only solution I've found so far too.

Comment: There should be a universal law that forces all IDEs and editors to include *one* setting to disable *all* auto-*everything*. Every single IDE makes this incredibly difficult.

Comment: Use vs-code default shortcut keys `ctrl+k` with `ctrl+shift+s` (windows) for saving without formatting.

Alternatively press `ctrl+shift+p` and search for **save without formatting**.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Had the same problem, just bind 'cmd + s' to *saving without formatting*.
press cmd+shift+p then search for save without formatting and click on the configure icon, then bind it with 'cmd + s', problem gone :)

Comment: This is the only solution that works for me. I cannot for the life of me understand why, but my VSCode installation INSISTS on formatting .js files.

Comment: @birgersp It's probably an extension, you can go to the command palette and search for the command "Start Extension Bisect". It will enable/disable a bunch of extensions and ask you if you're still having the problem a couple of times, until it's closed in on it enough for you to identify which extension it was causing whatever unwanted behavior. Then you can try and see if it's a configuration of that extension or just a bug that needs to be reported.

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me. I uninstalled prettier and tried but didn't work. Only this solution works for me.

Comment: Awesome.
Followed your advice:  View>Command pallete> typed "Save" on the text search field.
See "File: Save without formatting" on far right cog-wheel icon setting (clicked it),

Comment: This worked for me, thanks a lot. I have the same problem but with `html` files. vscode always reformats the html on save while I already formatted the document with prettier.

Comment: Works for the Gleam extension too, which otherwise does not have this option, and ignores the global `editor.formatOnSave` setting.

Answer (score 81):

Did you try adding

```
"editor.formatOnSave": false
```

in your user settings rather than in your project settings?

Comment: Can confirm that by default this `"editor.formatOnSave"` is off for VSCode user setting. Prettier may be doing something else here since it'll format on save even if this setting is off.

Comment: "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true
  }, <- this line maybe?

Comment: To find your settings in VS Code go to the File menu > Preferences > Settings. Then type `formatOnSave` into the search box. Uncheck the checkbox. Done!

Comment: where does these config exists?
I'm new to vscode. Is there a tutorial on all the basics I might need?

Answer (score 27):

In the case it is ESLint, and not Prettier, the solution is:

Open `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)` and configure:

```json
"editor.formatOnSave": false,
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll": false,
    "source.fixAll.eslint": false
}
```

I don't have Prettier but the solution may be similar.

Answer (score 17):

In my case, I uninstalled prettier and was using html-css-js code formatter. I had already unchecked format on save, and had tried many other methods. I finally changed a setting in formatter.json (settings of html-css-js formatter) and then it worked.

Steps:

1. ctrl + shift + P
2. Formatter Config
3. If "onSave": true, change true to false
4. Save the formatter.json and reload window.

[image: My formatter.json settings]

This worked for me. I can use auto-save after this as well.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that after struggling with this for a few days (!), this is the solution that worked for me! Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. This one worked for me as well.

Answer (score 11):

I came across this problem a while back. I disabled the `formatOnSave` option in settings.

Goto `File > Preferences > Settings` or `Ctrl + ,`.
In User tab choose `Text editor` and navigate

to `Formatting`, disable the `formatOnSave` option.

YW!

Comment: Well, there are no Preferences under File anymore 

Answer (score 7):

In my case I had two default code formatters that had conflicting settings,  "prettier" was set not to format on save but *JS-CSS-HTML Formatter* was still set as my default formatter for some file types.  I suggest using only one formatter and removing any unused / conflicting ones from your extensions list.

The way I used was to:

1. Open a file type ( one that's giving you formatting on save issues. )
2. Click on the file type and select "Configure 'yourFiletype' language based settings.. from the dropdown.
   [image]
3. Delete the line that sets your default formatter:  ex)       "editor.defaultFormatter": "lonefy.vscode-JS-CSS-HTML-formatter"
   [image]
4. Then go back to your file and try formatting normally, ( my hotkey is: alt + shift+ f  ), it should prompt you to select your default formatter.

This should help minimize conflicting formatters issues.

Comment: Had to add `"editor.formatOnSave": false`

Answer (score 7):

#### Save without Formatting

The ideal solution to this would be to use the "Save without Formatting" command.

This can be executed by either:

- Selecting it in the command palette: `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `P`
- Doing the keyboard shortcut: `CTRL` + `K`, `S`

This lets you save files, bypassing any formatters that may run automatically.

#### Format on Save

You might want to disable auto-formatting entirely. You might just not like it, or because it can be annoying when paired with `files.autoSave` which saves automatically, and therefore formats automatically too.

First check your global settings and see if you have `editor.formatOnSave` enabled. If so, then disable it.

You can navigate to your settings by either:

- Navigating the menu bar: `File` → `Preferences` → `Settings`
- Doing the keyboard shortcut: `CTRL` + `,`

Then search for `editor.formatOnSave` and disable it.

If it's still auto-formatting, then it might be enabled in workspace settings. Check if the root of the workspace has a file at `.vscode/settings.json`, and if so, if it has `editor.formatOnSave`. If it does, then either disable it there or delete the file to stop it from overriding your global settings.

#### Other Extensions

Check if any other extensions are performing code actions on save. Other answers here cover this topic a bit, but in general, you can navigate through your setting and search terms like "save" or "format".

---

All UI navigation and keyboard shortcuts are taken from the Linux installation, they may vary on other platforms.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it by changing the user settings file:

1. press `ctrl + shift + p`
2. go to the `preferences: Open User Settings(JSON)`

you can **disable** the format code on save **for all files** by adding the below code:

```json
{
    "editor.formatOnSave": false,
}
```

And if you wanna only **disable** formatting **for specific files** you can use the below code:

```json
{
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "[markdown]": 
    {
      "editor.formatOnSave": false
    },
    "[yaml]": {
       "editor.formatOnSave": false
    },
}
```

by using this code, formatting is disabled for `yaml` and `markdown` files but is enabled for the rest of the file formats.

---

hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps this [plugin called Formatting Toggle](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tombonnike.vscode-status-bar-format-toggle) by [tombonnike](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/publishers/tombonnike) can help you.

It disables the autosave with a toggle.

From its description:

> A VS Code extension that allows you to toggle the formatter (Prettier, Beautify, …) ON and OFF with a simple click.

Comment: I know you got downvoted a few times, but this is actually what i was looking for. Want to only turn it off sometimes , and as easy as possible :)

Comment: I wish this worked for me, but it did not. VsCode still refuses to NOT format on save.

Comment: @SethFalco you probably meant "**Save without Formatting**". Actually this was the only thing that worked for me, so I changed the default **keybinding** of `CTRL` + `s` to do it

Comment: @NoamManos Thanks for correcting me! Yes, indeed, **Save without Formatting**. Since I can't edit it, I'll just delete the previous comment to avoid future readers following wrong instructions.

Answer (score 4):

I've just stumbled across this question while experiencing the exact same problem. The way I solved it, was just to **switch the language of the document to plain text** (you can do so by clicking on the language in the bottom navigation bar). If you then hit "save", no reformatting happens.

Disadvantage: You get no syntax highlighting. But if you just want to fix a typo or something and don't want to mess with the settings or install an extension, it's probably an ok workaround.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem, tried disable all the installed extensions & confirmed format on save disabled, but still it's doing format every time when I hit control + s button. it's very annoying which breaks the source control a lot!

turns out I had a solution (not so pretty one I suppose ...), try bring up the command panel by clicking control + shift + p and search for save (or save without format) and click on the setting button
[image]
just swap the key binding for save with this command, that should do the trick!
[image]

Comment: wdym not so pretty, it's actually is pretty straightforward

Answer (score 1):

I just got the same problem and while trying these solutions, I realized that when you click ctrl + shift + P, and type "Save without formatting", the option will have a settings icon on the right corner, click there to configure keybinding, you can put any keybinding you want there, for example ctrl + k, which I put. It worked instantly and it was very easy, so you can have the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 1):

For me, when I delete the [JS-CSS-HTML Formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lonefy.vscode-JS-CSS-HTML-formatter) VS Code Extension, this issue is gone. Steps:

1. Open a file (in my case: `HTML`) and click `HTML` in the right bottom:

[image]

2. Click `Configure 'HTML' language based settings...`
3. Remove all object inside `[html]`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue lurking for a long time. My solution was to initially enable "formatOnsave",

`"editor.formatOnSave": true` -> `"editor.formatOnSave": false`

Answer (score 0):

Go to C:\Users[user]\AppData\Roaming\Code\User

and change the editor.formatOnSave option to false.

[image: editing settings.json]

Comment: this will work, but there are easier ways to change VSCode settings. The screenshot is also somewhat superfluous.

Comment: My format on save is already disabled

Comment: This should be obvious, but in case it isn't to anyone, the path provided is for Windows installations only. It'll live somewhere else if you're on macOS or Linux. Overall, not worth following this answer though compared to other more simple and platform-agnostic solutions.

Answer (score 0):

May not be for JS, but the `EditorConfig for VS Code` extension applies some formatting on save, including removing trailing whitespace (and it looks like you can't disable that, why?!)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Switching off here solved my problem.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case it the reason was that the project I was editing has `.vscode/settings.json` with `"editor.formatOnSave": true`

Answer (score 0):

i found out that:

## # fmt: off

Will not format this

## # fmt: on

will start formatting again from here in vscode

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to disable formatting on save for the current file or periodicaly, you can hit on MacOS:

`CMD` + `K`, then `S`

Will save without formatting.

If you do not have this shortcut :

`CMD` + `SHIFT` + `P` , then search for `Save` , you'll have `Save without Formatting` option with the associated shortcut shown on the right.