# No formatter is wanted, but VS Code keeps asking anyways for a default

Tags: visual-studio-code, notifications, formatter

**Background**

I use Prettier for most code/data files (CSS, JS, JSON, etc.). It integrates well into VSCode along with ESLint. I had only one problem with it - I didn't like how it formatted my HTML (or how the other built-in HTML formatter formatted it either). So, I changed my workspace settings.

```json
{
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": null
    }
}
```

I though, well that's out of the way now, and my HTML is free to be however it is.

**Problem**

Now after a while of coding, I notice a notification on the little bell in the corner, which reads:

> [info icon] There are multiple formatters for 'HTML' files. One of them should be configured as default formatter.
>
> [button "Configure..."]

I clicked Configure and it opened a select menu for the two HTML formatters, Prettier, and the built-in one. What I found confusing is that I've already explicitly specified that I don't want HTML formatting, and it asks again every time I save the HTML file, even after closing out the notification. It doesn't even consider an option for no formatter.

**What I expect**

There should be no formatting for HTML files, and it should not ask me to specify one of the formatters as a default.

**Questions and Answers I've read before**

[How do you determine which formatter is being used for VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49640469/14469685) is a notable one I've already researched - it is quite literally the reason I'm having this problem (see accepted answer in that question).

[VSCode - Disable ALL Auto Formatting on Save](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61827206/14469685) is a bit overkill - I don't want to **END ALL FORMATTING** (dark resonating voice), but only disable it for one language without it continuously asking.

Comment: Definitely agree here - not the most ideal setup and can lead to some annoyances. For example every time I save a `.gitignore` file it interrupts me to configure the formatter..